# Drawing a Tiled Logo over NSImage an 45 degree

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to draw a logo tiled over an image at 45 degrees.But I always get a spacing on the left side.

```
        var y_offset: CGFloat = logo.size.width * sin(45 * (CGFloat.pi / 180.0))
        // the sin of the angle may return zero or negative value,
        // it won't work with this formula
            
        if y_offset >= 0 {
        var x: CGFloat = 0
        while x < size.width {
            var y: CGFloat = 0
            while y < size.height {
                // move to this position
                context.saveGState()

                context.translateBy(x: x, y: y)
                // draw text rotated around its center
                context.rotate(by: ((CGFloat(-45) * CGFloat.pi ) / 180))

                logo.draw(at:NSPoint(x:x,y:y), from: .zero, operation: .sourceOver, fraction: CGFloat(logotransparency))
                
                // reset
                context.restoreGState()
                y = y + CGFloat(y_offset)
            }
            x = x + logo.size.width
        }}
    
    }
```

This is the result what I get.

[image]

As you can see there are some spacing present on the left side.I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.I have tried setting `y` to `size.height` and decrementing it by `y_offset` in the loop.But I get the same result.

Update:

```
var dirtyRect:NSRect=NSMakeRect(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
                let deg45 = CGFloat.pi / 4
                if let ciImage = logo.ciImage {
                          let ciTiled = ciImage.tiled(at: deg45).cropped(to: dirtyRect)
                let color = NSColor.init(patternImage: NSImage.fromCIImage(ciTiled))
                          color.setFill()
                          context.fill(dirtyRect)
                      }
```

Comment: Is `x, y` the center of the image or the bottom left corner? Is `context.translateBy(x: x, y: y)` and `logo.draw(at:NSPoint(x:x,y:y)` drawing at `(x: x * 2, y: y * 2)`?

Comment: @Willeke I think macOS coordinate system works like this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Devpedia-CocoaApp-MOSX/Art/window_coordinate.jpg

Comment: I know. Which point is `x, y` supposed to be? The comment is `// draw text rotated around its center`. What does the desired result look like?

Comment: @Willeke It should look this this (the direction doesn't matter) https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3bYk.jpg

Comment: Try drawing the image at `(0, 0)`.

Comment: @Willeke Thanks.That seems to do the trick. But there is no spacing between the drawn images.

Comment: Calculate and add `x_offset`?

Comment: @Willeke Can you post an example, I don't get it.

Comment: By the way, you can simplify your `while` loop and manual x/y calculations with just: `for x in stride(from: 0, to: size.width, by: logo.size.width) { ... }` and in it, nesting `for y in stride(from: 0, to: size.height, by: CGFloat(y_offset) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

If you need more control over the appearance you can go with manually drawing the overlays. See below code for a fixed version of your original code with two options for spacing.
In production, you would of course want to avoid using `!` and move the image loading out of the draw function (even though NSImage(named:) uses a cache).

```
override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    
    let bgImage = NSImage(named: "landscape")!
    bgImage.draw(in: dirtyRect)

    let deg45 = CGFloat.pi / 4
    let logo = NSImage(named: "TextTile")!
    
    let context = NSGraphicsContext.current!.cgContext
    
    let h = logo.size.height // (sin(deg45) * logo.size.height) + (cos(deg45) * logo.size.height)
    let w = logo.size.width  // (sin(deg45) * logo.size.width ) + (cos(deg45) * logo.size.width )

    var x: CGFloat = -w
    while x < dirtyRect.width + w {
        var y: CGFloat = -h
        while y < dirtyRect.height + h {
            context.saveGState()
            context.translateBy(x: x, y: y)
            context.rotate(by: deg45)
            logo.draw(at:NSPoint(x:0,y:0),
                      from: .zero,
                      operation: .sourceOver,
                      fraction: 1)
            context.restoreGState()

            y = y + h
        }
        x = x + w
    }

    super.draw(dirtyRect)
}
```

**Original answer**

You can set a backgroundColor with a patternImage to for the effect of drawing image tiles in a rect.
To tilt the image by some angle, use `CIImage`'s `CIAffineTile` option with some transformation.

Here is some example code:

```
import Cocoa
import CoreImage

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func loadView() {

        let size = CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)
        let view = TiledView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))

        self.view = view
    }
}

class TiledView: NSView {

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        let bgImage = NSImage(named: "landscape")!
        bgImage.draw(in: dirtyRect)

        let deg45 = CGFloat.pi / 4
        if let ciImage = NSImage(named: "TextTile")?.ciImage() {

            let ciTiled = ciImage.tiled(at: deg45).cropped(to: dirtyRect)
            let color = NSColor.init(patternImage: NSImage.fromCIImage(ciTiled))
            color.setFill()
            dirtyRect.fill()
        }
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
    }
}

extension NSImage {
    // source: https://rethunk.medium.com/convert-between-nsimage-and-ciimage-in-swift-d6c6180ef026

    func ciImage() -> CIImage? {

        guard let data = self.tiffRepresentation,
              let bitmap = NSBitmapImageRep(data: data) else {

            return nil
        }
        let ci = CIImage(bitmapImageRep: bitmap)
        return ci
    }

    static func fromCIImage(_ ciImage: CIImage) -> NSImage {

        let rep = NSCIImageRep(ciImage: ciImage)
        let nsImage = NSImage(size: rep.size)
        nsImage.addRepresentation(rep)
        return nsImage
    }
}

extension CIImage {

    func tiled(at angle: CGFloat) -> CIImage {

        // try different transforms here
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
        return self.applyingFilter("CIAffineTile", parameters: [kCIInputTransformKey: transform])
    }
}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.Can you also tell me why my approach above is failing.

Comment: 1. y_offset calculation does not make sense if you consider edge cases for a=0 and a=90 – they should both return 0 but in your case it's 0 and 1.     2. you translate by xy and then draw at xy resulting in double translation. Just pick one.

Comment: ok.. But in your approach there is just a background color.How do I draw this over an existing NSImage.Also how do I adjust the spacing between the drawn images?

Comment: I do the drawing just like you did – see my updated answer wit a bg image. from which context did you issue your drawing calls?

Comment: Please see the result image https://imgur.com/a/MossKsk

Comment: This is the result when I try to place this image https://imgur.com/a/76oBysD over the original image. As you can see there is no spacing present between these images.

Comment: Can you share more of your code?

Comment: Please see the update.It seems I need to add some transparent padding around the image for the spacing to appear.Also don't know how to make the tiled images transparent ?

Comment: Please see my updated answer. For transparency please post another question, it is out of scope.

Comment: @de. I made this comment on OPs post, but I'll copy/modify it here too: you can simplify your while loop and manual x/y calculations with just: `for x in stride(from: -w, to: dirtyRect.width + w, by: +w) { ... }` and in it, nesting `for y in stride(from: -h, to: dirtyRect.height + h, by: +h) { ... }`

Comment: @Alexander nice, I wasn’t aware!

Comment: @de. Would you like me to patch that into your answer?

Comment: @de. This is what I was looking for.Thanks a lot. For transparency I just needed to adjust the fraction `fraction`

Comment: I used the second option to set the spacing.I understand that you referred to setting the spacing between strides of the drawn logo.I was referring to the spacing between individual logos as now if the transparency pixels are stripped out , the logos overlap.Example using option 2 for spacing https://imgur.com/a/DXmm7E6 Please advice

Comment: You can apply the rotation first, then the whole canvas is tilted and you draw diagonal lines of images. You need to increase the drawing area to avoid blanks.

Comment: I have accepted your answer.Can you please help with this one regarding the padding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022034/add-transparent-padding-around-nsimage